# Variace covariance matrix using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
cov(1, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Covar(Range("f3:f241"), Range("h3:h41"))
```

Above is the vba code I tried out to get the covariance of two data vectors. But When I tried it in a different way I got an error

`cov(1, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Covar(Range(Cells(3, 6), Cells(241, 6)), Range(Cells(3, 7), Cells(241.7)))`

Where did I go wrong? Can some help please. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shouldn't there be a comma instead of a dot?

`Cells(241.7)` should be `Cells(241, 7)`

Also, worth knowing you can shorten this a bit if you dimension a *pointer* to the `Application.WorksheetFunction` like this

```
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

cov(1,1) = wf.Covar(Range("f3:f241"), Range("h3:h41"))
' or
cov(1,1) = wf.Covar(Range(Cells(3, 6), Cells(241, 6)), _ 
                    Range(Cells(3, 7), Cells(241,7)))
```

Comment: @Heisenberg no, that just splits the line - *cosmetics*. You can remove the `_` *underscore* and move the second `Range()` up to the same line as first `Range()`